# C# Console Application Individual Line Loading

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, console-application

I'm currently working in C# in visual studio 2010. I am working on console applications and was wondering if anyone knew a way to have Console.WriteLines appear on the console individually without key strokes? E.g. text that appears line by line. I've looked around quite a bit and can't seem to find a way to do it without using standard command lines rather than C#.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want a pause between each WriteLine()? If not please clarify.

Comment: This is very confusing, can you give an example? `Console.WriteLine()` prints an individual line to the console, and does not require keystrokes. It would help if you could give an example of what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

For each string you want on its own line, write that string to the console.

```
string a = "hello";
string b = "world";

Console.WriteLine(a);
Console.WriteLine(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put 
   `Console.ReadKey()`
between your line outputs. This will wait for any key to be pressed after every line.

Example:

```
Console.Write("Press any key to continue ...");
Console.ReadKey(true);
Console.WriteLine("DONE!")
```

This will print "Press any key to continue ..." then wait for any keystroke and add "DONE!" to the end of the line.

Comment: Unless the "key" is the enter key, actually any key pressed that has a visual representation will be inserted between the `Write` and `WriteLine`, to get the key so it doesn't appear in the console, use `Console.ReadKey(true)` instead, which hides the pressed key.

Comment: Good point @Ron Beyer. I'm going to adjust ma answer, but it seems the author has lost his interest to get the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone who replied, sorry it look my a long time to get back to this, I've been extremely busy. Sorry that my question was poorly phrased. What I was attempting to do was create an image with console.WriteLine();
I found that the way to do this was with system threading to create a delay between lines.